# How to replicate block of codes in new cells in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, offset

My data (number 1 to number 24) is in Column A. I want to create 6 tables to contain my data in a way shown below. I've created codes for the first table. What's the best way to code the remaining 5 tables? My actual product is a much bigger table and needs to replicate 100 times, so hard-coding is not possible. (will offset property help? how?)

Here's code for first table.

```
Sub DataToTable()

Range("C1:E3").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("C:M").ColumnWidth = 4.67
Range("C1:E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 27
Range("C2:C3").Interior.ColorIndex = 27

Range("D2").Value = Range("A1")
Range("E2").Value = Range("A2")
Range("D3").Value = Range("A3")
Range("E3").Value = Range("A4")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Don't have time to write a sample but I would trying using two `For` loops and the `Cells` method of selecting ranges.

Comment: Would you please provide a sample when you get time? I am not familiar and confused of how to use loops. Thank you!

Comment: Is your number always fits into the squares on the right (i.e. a power of 4)?

Comment: Each table is 24 x 16 (total 384 values taken from column A, filling from left to right in table, then top to bottom) Total table is 100.

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish this task, you have to use loops. I will share with you a working sample for that with variables that allow you to set parameters for the tables and also shows an example of the command For and one example of the command While. If you have any doubts about some specific part of the code, don't hesitate to ask.

```
Sub DataToTable()

Dim actualDataRow As Long
Dim tablesPerRow As Integer
Dim actualRowTable As Integer
Dim actualRow As Integer
Dim initialTableRow As Integer
Dim initialTableColumn As Integer

tablesPerRow = 3
actualRow = 0
actualRowTable = 0

initialTableRow = 2
initialTableColumn = 4

actualDataRow = 1

'Style columns (outside for)
Range(Columns(initialTableColumn), Columns(initialTableColumn + (tablesPerRow * 4))).ColumnWidth = 4.67

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(actualDataRow, 1))

    'Style table
    Range(Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) - 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) - 1), Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) + 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) + 1)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range(Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) - 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) - 1), Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) - 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    Range(Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) - 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) - 1), Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) + 1, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 27

    'Insert table data
    For x = 0 To 1
        For y = 0 To 1
            Cells(initialTableRow + (actualRow * 4) + x, initialTableColumn + (actualRowTable * 4) + y) = Cells(actualDataRow, 1)
            actualDataRow = actualDataRow + 1
        Next y
    Next x
    If actualRowTable >= tablesPerRow - 1 Then
        actualRowTable = 0
        actualRow = actualRow + 1
    Else
        actualRowTable = actualRowTable + 1
    End If

Wend

End Sub
```

Best regards,

Abe